# Recurring problem without using hash tables

Tags: javascript

This is a code for first recurring element and lets say as an input [2,5,5,2,3,5,1,2,4]
return 5 because the pairs are before 2,2 and im not able to return 5

```js
function firstRecurring(input) {
  for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
      if(input[i] === input[j]) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined
}

console.log(firstRecurring([2,5,5,2,3,5,1,2,4]));
```

Answer (score 1):

Your `j` index runs immediately to the end of the array. You should instead put a limit to how far you look and check the section before. So `j` should not be looking *ahead*, but *back*:

```js
function firstRecurring(input) {
  for (let i = 1; i < input.length; i++) {
    for (let j = 0; j < i; j++) {
      if(input[i] === input[j]) {
        return input[i];
      }
    }
  }
  return undefined;
}

console.log(firstRecurring([2,5,5,2,3,5,1,2,4]));
```

Of course, this can be made more efficient by using a set of encountered values. You can then also use the `for..of` syntax. And... `return undefined` is really not necessary, as it is the default behaviour:

```js
function firstRecurring(input) {
  let set = new Set;
  for (let val of input) {
    if (set.has(val)) return val;
    set.add(val);
  }
}

console.log(firstRecurring([2,5,5,2,3,5,1,2,4]));
```